# In the navigation bar is pushing away another part of it

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a navigation bar but I realize it is not fitting the container and .header is pushing away the .header .menu to the further side of the container or it is exceeding the container to be exact. For example, if the container is 1280px, it will be exceeding it.
By changing the width of .header, it can set in a suitable way but it will response poorly when the browser resize into a smaller version showing that it will not fit the current container it is in.

```
.header {
  background-color: #a5ffd6;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

Jsfiddle don't show the problem which show it in its perfect form but when using my own laptop to test, it will show the error which I speak of.
https://jsfiddle.net/uL31od2g/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace existing with following!

```
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}

.header {
  background-color: #a5ffd6;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  position: fixed;
  width: 80%;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

Comment: But by doing that, the site will not be responsive when window resizing. Example,From Full windows size to a smaller window size

Comment: On my computer all works good. Isn't max-width: 100% won't still work?

Comment: I am sorry for not specifying it properly.It works but what I wanted was not for the navigation bar to stretch to fit the width of the windows size but to the size of the wrapper.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with your example if you remove what I wrote. I tried resize a window, all work! As long as jsFiddle is not showing any problems I cannot help you! Please, be specific and provide a picture or a view of the problem!

Comment: What I was is for it to fit the container of a max-width of 1280px.But the current problem is it is pushing another part of it.By removing max-width of 1280px,it will just stretch out which is not desired.Here is the link.https://postimg.org/image/xez34eyp9/

Comment: Also the first div `<div id="wrapper">` doesn't have a close tag!

Comment: Opps Mistake but it still does not change anything.P.S Thanks for noticing the small mistake.

Comment: Replace existing with following and see if it works for your goal

`#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}`



`.header {
  background-color: #a5ffd6;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  position: fixed;
  width: 80%;
  z-index: 3;
}`
Sorry cannot format well here, will transfer to answer as well!

Comment: It works now and Thanks a million.Why does the change of width affect the outcome so dynamically?

Comment: Right now both match the width I mean `wrapper` and `header`! Try to stick with the width and do not use `px` without purpose! Also, this solution might cause some problems in future development, it depends on you future features!!!

Comment: So to be exact, both width must match and using px will affect the outcome? If I am right, I will keep this in mind from now on.Thanks

Comment: Try)) put back to `wrapper` -> `max-width: 1280px;` and you will see! And yes, if you apply width to something and then apply to that something `px` it might brake it!!!

Comment: Thanks for the advice and help.I am indebted to you